# Two questions about Requests and BS4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests    
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
import time    
import sys

url = "https://www.doviz.com/"    
response = requests.get(url)    
html_icerigi = response.content    
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_icerigi,"html.parser")    
isimler = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"menu-row1"})    
degerler = soup.find_all("span",{"class":"menu-row2"})    
islem = input("Lütfen işleminizi giriniz...")    
time.sleep(1)

for isim,deger in zip(isimler,degerler):    
    isim = isim.text    
    deger = deger.text    
    isim = isim.strip()    
    deger = deger.strip()    
    isim = isim.replace("\n","")    
    deger = deger.replace("\n","")    
    print(isim,deger)

    while True:    
        if islem == "q" or islem == "Q":    
            print("Programdan çıkılıyor...")    
        time.sleep(1)    
        elif islem == "1":   
            print("1 Gr Altın = {} TLdir.".format(deger[0]))
```

My questions are:

1. When i run this code because of the while loop inside of the for loop it gives an output like:

1 Gr Altın = 2 TLdir.
1 Gr Altın = 2 TLdir.

continuously. How can I avoid that?

2. `deger[0]` returns just the first digit of the real value of gram of gold. I want  all of it like 216,370 USD.

By the way im an absolute beginner to Python.

Best Regards.

Comment: 1) you have this nested in a `while True` loop.  By its very nature, this will continue forever.  Change the loop or add a conditional `break`.  2) It looks like you are indexing the `deger` string.  The `0` index of a string is it's first letter

Comment: Thanks for your comment DYZ, why is it turning a letter not the whole value? Probably because it is  a string so should I convert it to float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no need for the `while True:` loop.  Dropping that will get rid of problem #1

Similarly, it looks like you are indexing the `deger` string. The 0 index of a string is it's first letter.  Dropping the indexing will return the entire value.

EDIT:
From your comments, it looks like you are trying to make a list that you can index to pull up the specific value of that index.  In order to do this, you need to make a list of the values.

```
look_up = []
for isim,deger in zip(isimler,degerler):
    isim = isim.text
    deger = deger.text
    isim = isim.strip()
    deger = deger.strip()
    isim = isim.replace("\n","")
    deger = deger.replace("\n","")
    look_up.append(isim + "\t" + deger)
    print(isim,deger)

# dedent to remove from `for` loop
if islem == "q" or islem == "Q":
    print("Programdan çıkılıyor...")
    time.sleep(1)
else:
    print("1 Gr Altın = {} TLdir.".format(look_up[int(islem)]))
```

Note: this will only allow one lookup.  If you want it to allow for more than one lookup, you will need to institute a sentinel loop whereby the loop continues until `"q"` is pressed.

Additionally, you may be better served utilizing a dictionary `look_up = {}` and populating it through `look_up[isim] = deger`.  That way you can just look up the info by the `isim` value.  i.e `DOLAR` or `EURO`

I hope this is enough information to get you where you are trying to go.  I trust you can use the info given here to solve your specific use case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I need to iterate in my "deger" value. I'm trying to get currency values from an Internet website and storing the names of currencies in "isimler" list, storing the values of currencies as Turkish Lira in "degerler" list.
After that Im asking an input to user about his operations. Such as the value of 1 USD  as Turkish Lira so I want to operate in "deger" but at this line 

"deger = deger.text"

I convert the deger value into a text and the first index of a string is a letter but is there anyway?

Comment: You are already iterating your `deger` values in your `for` loop.  Each step in the in the loop grabs the next value in your `degerler` list.  If you look at the output from your `print(isim,deger)` line, you see the entire `deger` value.  This means that you don;t need to index it at all to get its value.

Comment: I think I couldn't adress my problem to you. If I use ".format(deger)" only it just returns the same value over and over but I want to make it to vary. For example if user press "1" the program will give the value of 1 USD as TRY. If user press "2" the program will give the value of EUR as TRY such as. I hope you understand me now.

Best regards.

Comment: Ah... okay.  You might have to pull that code out of the `for` loop then.  In the `for` loop, it is going to grab each value.  I'll update my answer with this new info when I get the chance.